# UWP - Subclassing built-in controls and inheriting styling behaviors

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

Is it possible to subclass a control (`AppBarToggleButton` in my case) and "inherit" `TargetType` of the base class? What I want to achieve is to have a slightly customized AppBarToggleButton (with disabled auto-toggle behavior) put into `CommandBar` and make it look exactly as if it was regular `AppBarToggleButton` (i.e. receive style whatever is defined for `AppBarToggleButton` inside given command bar control template). They say, `DefaultStyleKey` should help, but it is inherited fine, but, alas, doesn't seem to participate in local style resolution/lookup.

Comment: Could explain what's mean of auto-toggle behavior?

Comment: Auto-toggle means IsChecked property changes automatically on click, but that's not really a scope of the question - I may need to subclass other controls for various purposes, so the ultimate goal here is to understand how local style resolution works internally and does target instance has any involvement in it or is it a completely external process.

Answer (score 1):

> I may need to subclass other controls for various purposes, so the ultimate goal here is to understand how local style resolution works internally and does target instance has any involvement in it or is it a completely external process.

In general, we need make **Templated Control** for custom `AppBarToggleButton`. When we make Templated Control with Visual Studio, it will generate `Generic.xaml` file in the **Themes** folder that used to declare the custom control's style. And the the custom control cs file like the following.

```
public sealed class CustomAppBarToggleButton : AppBarToggleButton
{
    public CustomAppBarToggleButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomAppBarToggleButton);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to edit the default style you could remove `DefaultStyleKey` line that used to binding current control with the style in the Generic.xaml file.

Open `Generic.xaml` file you will find the following. And it's empty style. If we want to do some  small changes, you need copy the complete `AppBarToggleButton` style to replace it and edit the `TargetType` to `local:CustomAppBarToggleButton`. Then you can edit the style base on your requirement.

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomAppBarToggleButton" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomAppBarToggleButton">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And if your want to make a new dependency property, please define it in the cs file then use `TemplateBinding` to bind the property in the style. For more please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/control-templates).

Comment: I'm not creating a brand new control, I'm just augmenting existing control's internal logic (and it even has override points for that) and I want it to behave same as base control UI-wise. So, long story short, I want class B (which extends class A) to receive same(!) implicit(!!!) styles as class A (including those defined in local "Resources" tag).

Comment: @Dmitry, Sure you could make class A inherit B without edit the default style. And you could do some basic process such to detect input event internal.

Comment: To illustrate further: CommandBarRevealStyle has implicit style for AppBarButtons defined as <Style TargetType="AppBarButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}" />. Now I want all CustomAppBarButtons to receive this local implicit style when added to CommandBar with CommandBarRevealStyle without explicitly editing/assigning any command bar styles.

Comment: If we don't specify the x:key for the style, the  CustomAppBarButton will local implicit style. in other words, the local implicit style will override the default style.

Comment: Indeed. But what I want is to have *all* implicit styles defined for "AppBarButton" automagically applied to "CustomAppBarButton"s as well.

Comment: Problem is, it won't be. Documentation for `TargetType` specifically states: "Implicit styles don't apply to elements that are subtypes of the type referenced as the TargetType value." and what I want is to override this behavior and make base type style applied to subtype.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my original question, `DefaultStyleKey` is already inherited as "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarButton", but AppBarButton implicit styles still does not apply. So, I'm still looking for a correct solution (if there's one).

Comment: Yep, you are correct, we need to specify target type as the custom control.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still stumbling upon this. I managed to solve a similar issue, inheriting from Button, using the approach described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71338869/10468107

Specifically, adding

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}" TargetType="local:MyButton" />
```

solved it for me. So maybe it works for other types as well, using `{StaticResource Default<TYPE>Style}`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need and am wondering if the answer is still the same. I have extended the basic ComboBox control to meet some behavioral requirements.

```
class ExtendedComboBox : ComboBox
```

I want the ExtendedComboBox instances to inherit the latest platform styling but they are instead getting styled differently. The first of these is an ExtendedComboBox (square corners, larger glyph), while the second is a generic ComboBox (rounded corners, smaller glyph).

[image]

The requirement is to have the two combo boxes styled the same way. I am reluctant to create an explicit Style for ExtendedComboBox because then if the style for the generic ComboBox changes the ExtendedComboBox will no longer match. Is there some way to just inherit the standard style?