# Inheriting descendant of WinUI-UserControl does not inherit all styles

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui-3, winui

When inheriting a TextBox, not all styles are respected by the child (see image in appendix).

```
<TextBox
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"/>
```

```
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    
    namespace AdvoTools.PerfectTimeNative.UI.Controls
    {
        public sealed partial class TextInput : TextBox
        {
            public TextInput() => InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

I tried different approaches:

- Inheriting as above results in certain styles missing;
- Copying the hardcoded `TextBox` styles from `generic.xaml` and setting their target to the inherited control results into the same effect;
- using templated controls as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016697/uwp-subclassing-built-in-controls-and-inheriting-styling-behaviors) does not seem to work either. When I create it through the templated control preset for UWP and change the namespaces from Windows to Microsoft, the control is empty (the generated `generic.xaml` does not appear to be respected at all. Deleting it altogether makes no difference);
- Defining a style with the `BasedOn` property has the same reuslt as the first approach.

Note:

[image]

- The blue bottom border thickness does not increase when the `TextBox` is focused (not visible here);
- the corder radius is 0.

This should be a no-brainer but I am really struggling at the moment.

Comment: What's the XAML file for? Did you try just creating a custom class without any XAML file?, e.g.: `public class TextInput : TextBox { }`

Comment: @mm8 Yes, as in attempt three. After noticing that `generix.xaml` had no effect I was left with the non-partial class. Also tried things like `InitializeComponent()` or `base.InitializeComponent()` inside its constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Create a standalone custom class:

```
public class MyCustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyCustomTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyCustomTextBox);
    }
}
```

And add the following default template for it to `themes/generic.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyCustomTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}" />
```

Then it should look like a default `TextBox`.

Comment: `DefaultTextBoxStyle` was exactly what I was looking for. All my additional approaches work as well with this one. But where is this defined? It does not lie inside the `generic.xaml` file installed on the System, nor does Intellisense recognize it as valid.

Comment: It's included in the theme resources that ship with the SDK/framework.

Comment: Where can I look these up? `Installed with the SDK` sounds a lot like the styles located at `\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\<SDK version>\Generic` but they are not.